# Find replacement Electric bicycle battery lock / cylinder

Tags: lock, battery

I have a XEED E CITY electric bicycle and the company utilizes a simple wafer battery lock [image: XEED City Electric] The lock itself comes from a company called TKM.  I have lost my key and I would like to replace the whole mechanism. The problem is that the lock is made of a single piece of metal that bolts onto the frame and I'm having trouble finding a lock with a similar design.[image: Battery lock] Can you guys help me identify which type of lock this is and where could I buy a replacement?

Comment: Does this lock have a switch as well, to energise the bike from the battery?   Or is it purely a mechanical lock holding battery to bike ?

Comment: Its a purely mechanical lock. Simple waffle cylinder

Answer (score 1):

That’s going to be a proprietary part made for XEED. Limited chance of buying one off the shelf.

If XEED can’t provide a new module maybe you can get the lock core replaced which would be a job for a locksmith or an experienced lock picker since you don’t have the key.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Take that part to a competent locksmith.   They will be able to tell you what is possible and what it will cost for a replacement core and keys.

Lock cores and their internals are a bit beyond the home DIY mechanic.

---

Or simply use a large velcro strap around battery and downtube to hold it together, AND always take the battery inside with you; never leave it on the bike unattended.